# Get all Comments for Author. Secondary join using Ecto Models

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have three models that are similar to this

```
schema "Author" do
  has_many :posts, Repo.Post
end

schema "Post" do
  has_many :comments Repo.Post
  belongs_to :author, Repo.Author
end

schema "Comment" do
  belongs_to :post, Repo.Post
end
```

how do I create a field or method for Author to display all comments? Essentially a secondary join. I need to be able to expose this to an Absinthe schema somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Use [has_many :through](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_many/3-has_many-has_one-through)

```
schema "Author" do
  has_many :posts, Repo.Post
  has_many :comments, through: [:posts, :comments]
end
```

Comment: I got a `no match of right hand side value: %Ecto.Association.HasThrough` I think because unlike the example in the link you provided, my `posts` (secondary table) don't belong to `comments`. In other words, they don't have a `comment_id`.